# Problema al construir url amigables con .htaccess en page hecha con react-js cuando se navega con protocolo https

Tags: .htaccess, reactjs, https, mod-rewrite

Tengo un site que utilizo `mod_rewrite` para hacer las url amigables,al hacer peticion a una pagina por protocolo http si me toma bien las reglas que tengo en el .htaccess, pero si hago peticion por https no las toma bien

mi .htaccess seria algo como esto:

```
 Options -MultiViews
 Options All -Indexes
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule ^panel/([a-zA-Z0-9-_/]*)?$ api/admin_dev.php?show=$1 [L]       
 RewriteRule ^[a-zA-Z0-9-_/]*$ index.html [NC,L]
```

donde el index.html seria el index de una page hecha con react, si navego a esta ruta http://midominio.com/panel/ me va bien a mi script php q esta en el directorio public_html/api/admin_dev.php, si navego a http://midominio.com o http://midominio.com/blog me va bien a la page hecha en react.
Ahora si navego a esas mismas url pero con https entra siempre a la page react como si no tomara en cuenta la regla para cuando viene "panel" en la url

Comment: repite las reglas para https tambien

Comment: las reglas no las pongo en la configuración de los virtualhost, tengo el .htaccess en la carpeta public_html, no debería ahí ya tomar las reglas para cualquiera de los 2 protocolos, donde especifico si es para uno o para el otro?

Comment: Las reglas se aplican indistintamente, .htaccess aplica a nivel de contexto de directorio. El error no aplica a mod_rewrite al menos que también lo utilices para desactivar el trafico HTTP y redirigirlo a HTTPS. ¿Eres el administrador del servidor? ¿Es un hosting compartido? ¿Puedes facilitar un poco de tu fichero .htaccess dónde aplicas mod_rewrite?